# Using grep display lines of context before back to the first line matching something else before the matched line?

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep

So say I find a match with `grep -e` and I want to print all the lines from the match back to another match, like `----` for instance.

Is that possible, or do I have to use another command like `awk` or something to do that?

Like for instance, if I have the following file:

```
----
Ticket Number: 5465415312

Software Services
Notepad
Text

Description: 
My Notepad won't type text.
```

The output should be like:

```
----
Ticket Number: 5465415312

Software Services
```

And it matches again up back to `----` from `Software Services`

Comment: Please proof read. This question is very unclear, and lacks grammar. As such and answers would be guesses at what you want.

Comment: What if there is no previous ---?

Comment: @JeffSchaller I'll put one at the top.

Comment: Awk is probably a better tool for what you want.  Hard to tell from what you posted and if your file is or is not of uniform syntax

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17988756/how-to-select-lines-between-two-marker-patterns-which-may-occur-multiple-times-w

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -n '/----/,/Software Services/{p;/Software Services/q}' file
```

Output:

```
----
Ticket Number: 5465415312

Software Services
```

Comment: Nice use of sed, but the op is asking to print lines before or after matching a (single) pattern (I am not sure exactly) not matching multiple patterns or print lines between two patterns (a job for awk IMO).

Comment: @Panther This is the `sed` way of doing it. The question implicitly talks about _two_ patterns.  One pattern to trigger output and another to delimit from where the output should start.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`, the short way of doing it:

```
awk '/^----$/,/^Software Services$/' file
```

The long and roundabout way of doing it:

```
awk '/^----$/              { lines = "" }
                           { lines = (lines == "" ? $0 : lines ORS $0) }
     /^Software Services$/ { print lines }' file
```

That is, empty the string saved in `lines` every time we hit a line of four dashes.  Then always append the current line to `lines`, and print the contents of `lines` when we find the "trigger" line in the input data.